# Clicking ENTER after CTRL+S does nothing

Tags: 22.04

I have Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with Wayland. I switched from Fedora to Ubuntu and noticed that the Ctrl+s plus Enter doesn't work. I have to move my mouse to the "Save" button on the top right every time for it to save. I have had various Linux distros and this has never happened. I have also had Ubuntu for years and this has never happened with Ubuntu. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Edit: showing behavior of what happens when pressing CTRL+S. There are about 30 s in the address bar that show up after pressing Ctrl+s

[image]

**Edit2: So what happens is that after Ctrl+s, "ssssssssssssssssssssss..." appears in the address bar and continues indefinitely unless I stop it by clicking with my mouse somewhere. The "sssssssssssss..." appears on any webpage that allows text to be written. What could be the problem here? Firefox, Chrome, Chromium all have this behavior.**

Comment: Which app are you using where ctrl+s does not save?

Comment: Can you check whether switching to X.Org changes the behavior?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi form what I see, only different browsers (firefox, chrome, chromium). And what is also weird is that for browsers the "s" button seems to be held down but not physically so in the address bar about 30 "s"s show up. It is strange behavior. Ctrl+S works for all other programs it seems.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi okay I can try that

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi i have added an image of what it looks like in the address bar after using ctrl+s

Comment: @mikanim no you haven't

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi forgor the image

Comment: Do you have sticky keys or some other accessibility option enabled?

Comment: @muru it only does this on browsers so no to both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was, as is typical with Ubuntu, to uninstall Firefox from the stupid version in the Ubuntu software and download it via the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`^S` (`XOFF`) is used to stop the output stream (`STDOUT` and `STDERR`) to the terminal.

The output stream must be continued by typing `^Q` (`XON`).

Read `man stty`.

Comment: They're describing a "Save" button which is not found in most terminal emulators, and their edit shows that they were talking about the Chromium browser

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with my problem. I would be in a browser and click CTRL+S. After clicking this, "sssssssssssssssssssssssssss...." appears up in the address bar. Weirdly, CTRL+Q pauses the "sssssss..." but it continues afterward.